# Can't add maven module in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1 (Latest version) and I just can't create a new maven module to my project. I have a parent project packaged as pom, as I'm using it just to handle some dependencies and settings across all child modules. In order to create new child modules, all I had to do till now was right click it's name in the project panel, click "New" -> "Module" -> "Maven" and then just complete the name, artifactId, and version fields and hit Finish at the end. The thin is, it does work, but it doesn't show up as a maven module. It looks just like a normal folder in my project view.
I even know why: Normally, maven modules should contain the "isMavenModule" tag marked as true inside the module's iml file, but my iml file doesn't even have that setting:

```
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
```

That's all it has, while my other modules look like this:

```
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
```

What makes it all even stranger is that I can easily create modules if they have a different name. I tried creating a test module called, well, "test" which I used the exact same way of creating as the other module, with the only difference being it's name. It does work as expected and I can't really see why this happens. While I can technically bypass this issue by manually adding the isMavenModule tag to my module's iml file, I'm intrigued by what is actually causing this.

Comment: What is the name you give to the module when it does NOT work?
Also, click the "Event log" on bottom right and see if it shows any errors.

Comment: @Bajal nope, just the usual "All files are up to date". As for the name, I know it might sound weird but it's 1_8_R3. The thing is, I have a bunch of modules like this one which aim to bring the same functionality but for different minecraft versions (it's a minecraft plugin I'm making) and all of them have simillar names, like 1_8_R2 for instance, and those all work fine.

Comment: Have you already tried the `Reimport all maven projects` aka blue refresh icon in the upper left corner of the Maven tool window?

Comment: The log (`Help > Show Log`) might provide some information as to what went wrong. Sounds like some type of edge case is being hit with the name you are using. (FYI, "1_8_R3" worked ok in my project. So something possibly about your project is causing it.). If you are _really_ curious, shutdown IDEA, turn on debug logging in `<ideaInstallDir>/bin/log.xml` and then do the module add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, thank you for the help guys, but apparently the issue was much simpler than I though. It seems that at some point I created a module in that project with the exact same name, which I later deleted (I don't remember why). The issue was that I just removed the module from the parent pom and simply deleted the folder that contained the module, but I didn't remove the configuration options of the project that intellij kept using (by that I mean those xml files in the IdeaProjects//.idea folder that contain various info for the editor). So all I had to do was manually open those files and 'CTRL+F' through them to remove all entries that referred in some way to the module '1_8_R3'. This seems to have solved the issue, but the good thing is that I finally learned how to properly delete a module... 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/removing-modules-from-a-project.html